# Unwanted change of tick position in pgfplot's smithchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

when I use pgfplot's smithchart in conjunction with altering the decimal separator to comma, some weird change in position of the x-axis ticks are happening.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}

\pgfplotsset{ every axis label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}, every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, set thousands separator={ }}
% THIS IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[scale=1]
    \addplot[mark=*, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates {
        (0.23076923, -0.51282051) (-0.32873098, -0.45626227) (-0.55950021, 0.05655824) (-0.23076923, 0.51282051) (0.32873098, 0.45626227) (0.55950021, -0.05655824) (1,0) (-1,0) (0,0)
    };
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue, mark=*, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates { (0.10750507, -0.12170385)
    };
    \path[draw=black, dashed] (1,0) circle (1.6cm);
    \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The 0,2 and 0,5 on the x-axis are higher than the other numbers. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a text depth to the tick label:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}

\pgfplotsset{ every axis label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}, every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize,text depth=.25ex}} % text depth added

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, set thousands separator={ }}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[scale=1]
    \addplot[mark=*, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates {
        (0.23076923, -0.51282051) (-0.32873098, -0.45626227) (-0.55950021, 0.05655824) (-0.23076923, 0.51282051) (0.32873098, 0.45626227) (0.55950021, -0.05655824) (1,0) (-1,0) (0,0)
    };
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue, mark=*, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates { (0.10750507, -0.12170385)
    };
    \path[draw=black, dashed] (1,0) circle (1.6cm);
    \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```